# How to read the save text file in a directory using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am save a file  in directory  having some data but now Need to read that file in phone gap .I try this but i am not able to read file.
Here is my save file and read file code?I am not getting any read data ? I also study phonegap documeny but not able to read

```
function saveDataOnTextFile(){
 try {
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
               function(fileSystem) {
                   fileSystem.root.getDirectory(CASENAME, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(directoryEntry) {
                       console.log("log folder is created");
                       directoryEntry.getFile(DOCUMENT_NAME+".rtf", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
                           fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                               writer.seek(writer.length);

                               writer.write($('#realTimeContents').text());
                           }, fail);
                       }, fail);
                   }, fail);
               },
               fail);
       }
       catch(e) {
           fail(e+"fail");
       }

}

function readRtfFile(){


 try {
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
               function(fileSystem) {
                   fileSystem.root.getDirectory(CASENAME, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(directoryEntry) {
                       console.log("log folder is created");
                       directoryEntry.getFile(DOCUMENT_NAME+".rtf", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
                           fileEntry.createReader(function(reader) {
                               reader.readEntries(function(entries){
                                var i;
                               for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                                console.log(entries[i].name);
                                }

                               },fail);


                           }, fail);
                       }, fail);
                   }, fail);
               },
               fail);
       }
       catch(e) {
           fail(e+"fail");
       }




}
```